# Error: SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `pt_participant`

Tags: database

I have problem with function insert. I've got error SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `pt_participant. Unfortunatelly i don't know what m'i doing wrong. Code look ok to me. Please help. My code:

```
    global $wpdb;
    $data = array( 
    'id'=>'',
    'course_id' => (int)$formElements['tripId'],
    'name_and_surname_participant' => $formElements['participantNameSurname'], 
    'date_of_birth' => $formElements['participatntDateOfBirth'],
    'PESEL_participant' => (int)$formElements['participantPESEL'], 
    'comments' => $formElements['participantComment'],
    'name_and_surname_parent' => $formElements['parentNameAndSurname'], 
    'PESEL_parent' => (int)$formElements['parentPESEL'],
    'ID_document' => $formElements['parentIDdocument'], 
    'street' => $formElements['street'],
    'house_number' => (int)$formElements['houseNumber'], 
    'post_id' => $formElements['postID'],
    'city' => $formElements['city'],
    'telephone_number' => (int)$formElements['telephoneNumber'], 
    'email_adress' => $formElements['email'],

    'payment' => (float)0.0,
    'pay_to_date' => date('Y-m-d'),
    'status' => (int)0,
    'contract' => (int)0,
    'regulations' => (int)0,
    'RODO' => (int)0,
    'card' => (int)0,
    'settlement' => (int)0,
    'startPoint' => (int)$formElements['listOfCities']
    ); 

    try{
        $wpdb->show_errors();
        $wpdb->insert('pt_participant', $data);
        echo $wpdb->print_error();
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
    echo $e->getCode().' : '.$e->getMessage();
    }}
```

And that's my database:

[image]

Comment: First of all. Id column is autoincrement, so you shouldn’t set it in your insert - it may cause conflicts.

Comment: i fought the same, but without id i still recive the same error.

Comment: I found a source of problem. Email field was too small and cannot handle full emails.

Comment: have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29932863/wpdb-insert-not-working-last-query-doesnt-show-insert-show-full-columns-fro) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29932863/wpdb-insert-not-working-last-query-doesnt-show-insert-show-full-columns-fro)?

Comment: unfortunatelly i didn't, but i figure it out on myself